# d3.js Date vs Half hour heat map not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to create a Date vs time heat map based on this https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3202354

The changes I am trying to do:

- X axis still has dates
- Y axis will have 24 hours of the day in half hour intervals (00:00:00, 00:30:00, 01:00:00, 01:30:00 so on). Therefore 48 ticks

I have managed to modify the code so far which is below. The two problems are:

1. Y axis does not have labels
2. Data goes one tick below x axis

I am a D3 noob (this is my first hands on experiment) and struggling with it.

d3+HTML+CSS code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
 
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
 
.label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
 
.tile {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
 
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
 
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js?2.9.6"></script>
<script>
 
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse,
    formatDate = d3.time.format("%b %d");

var parseTimeBucket = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse,
    formatTimeBucket =d3.time.format("%H:%M");  

var StartTime = parseTimeBucket("00:00:00");
var EndTime = parseTimeBucket("23:59:59");  
 
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
    z = d3.scale.linear().range(["white", "black"]);
 
// The size of the buckets in the CSV data file.
// This could be inferred from the data if it weren't sparse.
var xStep = 864e5,
    yStep = 18e5;
 
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
 
d3.csv("TimeDateHeatMap.csv", function(buckets) {
 
  // Coerce the CSV data to the appropriate types.
  buckets.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.bucket = parseTimeBucket(d.bucket);
    d.count = +d.count;
  });
 
  // Compute the scale domains.
  x.domain(d3.extent(buckets, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([StartTime, EndTime]);
 // y.domain(d3.extent(buckets, function(d) { return d.bucket; }));
  //console.log(d3.extent(buckets, function(d) { return d.bucket; }));
  z.domain([0, d3.max(buckets, function(d) { return d.count; })]);
 
  // Extend the x- and y-domain to fit the last bucket.
  // For example, the y-bucket 3200 corresponds to values [3200, 3300].
  x.domain([x.domain()[0], +x.domain()[1] + xStep]);
  y.domain([y.domain()[0], +y.domain()[1] + yStep]);
 
  // Display the tiles for each non-zero bucket.
  // See http://bl.ocks.org/3074470 for an alternative implementation.
  svg.selectAll(".tile")
      .data(buckets)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "tile")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.bucket); })
      .attr("width", x(xStep) - x(0))
      .attr("height", y(0) - y(yStep))
      .style("fill", function(d) { return z(d.count); });
 
  // Add a legend for the color values.
  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(z.ticks(6).slice(1).reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (width + 20) + "," + (20 + i * 20) + ")"; });
 
  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("width", 20)
      .attr("height", 20)
      .style("fill", z);
 
  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", 26)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(String);
 
  svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width + 20)
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text("Count");
 
  // Add an x-axis with label.
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).ticks(d3.time.days).tickFormat(formatDate).orient("bottom"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Date");
 
  // Add a y-axis with label.
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      //.call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"))
      .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(d3.time.minutes).tickFormat(formatTimeBucket).orient("left"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .text("Value");
});
 
</script>
```

TimeDateHeatMap.csv:

```
date,bucket,count
7/20/2012,00:00:00,119
7/20/2012,00:30:00,123
7/20/2012,01:00:00,173
7/20/2012,01:30:00,226
7/20/2012,02:00:00,284
7/20/2012,02:30:00,257
7/20/2012,03:00:00,268
7/20/2012,03:30:00,244
7/20/2012,04:00:00,191
7/20/2012,04:30:00,204
7/20/2012,05:00:00,187
7/20/2012,05:30:00,177
7/20/2012,06:00:00,164
7/20/2012,06:30:00,125
7/20/2012,07:00:00,140
7/20/2012,07:30:00,109
7/20/2012,08:00:00,103
7/21/2012,08:30:00,123
7/21/2012,09:00:00,165
7/21/2012,09:30:00,237
7/21/2012,10:00:00,278
7/21/2012,10:30:00,338
7/21/2012,11:00:00,306
7/21/2012,11:30:00,316
7/21/2012,12:00:00,269
7/21/2012,12:30:00,271
7/21/2012,13:00:00,241
7/21/2012,13:30:00,188
7/21/2012,14:00:00,174
7/21/2012,14:30:00,158
7/21/2012,15:00:00,153
7/21/2012,15:30:00,132
7/22/2012,16:00:00,154
7/22/2012,16:30:00,241
7/22/2012,17:00:00,246
7/22/2012,17:30:00,300
7/22/2012,18:00:00,305
7/22/2012,18:30:00,301
7/22/2012,19:00:00,292
7/22/2012,19:30:00,253
7/22/2012,20:00:00,251
7/22/2012,20:30:00,214
7/22/2012,21:00:00,189
7/22/2012,21:30:00,179
7/22/2012,22:00:00,159
7/22/2012,22:30:00,161
7/22/2012,23:00:00,144
7/22/2012,23:30:00,139
7/22/2012,00:00:00,132
7/22/2012,00:30:00,136
7/22/2012,01:00:00,105
7/23/2012,01:30:00,120
7/23/2012,02:00:00,156
7/23/2012,02:30:00,209
7/23/2012,03:00:00,267
7/23/2012,03:30:00,299
7/23/2012,04:00:00,316
7/23/2012,04:30:00,318
7/23/2012,05:00:00,307
7/23/2012,05:30:00,295
7/23/2012,06:00:00,273
7/23/2012,06:30:00,283
7/23/2012,07:00:00,229
7/23/2012,07:30:00,192
7/23/2012,08:00:00,193
7/23/2012,08:30:00,170
7/23/2012,09:00:00,164
7/23/2012,09:30:00,154
7/23/2012,10:00:00,138
7/23/2012,10:30:00,101
7/23/2012,11:00:00,115
7/23/2012,11:30:00,103
7/24/2012,12:00:00,105
7/24/2012,12:30:00,156
7/24/2012,13:00:00,220
7/24/2012,13:30:00,255
7/24/2012,14:00:00,308
7/24/2012,14:30:00,338
7/24/2012,15:00:00,318
7/24/2012,15:30:00,255
7/24/2012,16:00:00,278
7/24/2012,16:30:00,260
7/24/2012,17:00:00,235
7/24/2012,17:30:00,230
7/24/2012,18:00:00,185
7/24/2012,18:30:00,145
7/24/2012,19:00:00,147
7/24/2012,19:30:00,157
7/24/2012,20:00:00,109
7/25/2012,20:30:00,104
7/25/2012,21:00:00,191
7/25/2012,21:30:00,201
7/25/2012,22:00:00,238
7/25/2012,22:30:00,223
7/25/2012,23:00:00,229
7/25/2012,23:30:00,286
7/25/2012,00:00:00,256
7/25/2012,00:30:00,240
7/25/2012,01:00:00,233
7/25/2012,01:30:00,202
7/25/2012,02:00:00,180
7/25/2012,02:30:00,184
7/25/2012,03:00:00,161
7/25/2012,03:30:00,125
7/25/2012,04:00:00,110
7/25/2012,04:30:00,101
7/26/2012,05:00:00,132
7/26/2012,05:30:00,117
7/26/2012,06:00:00,124
7/26/2012,06:30:00,154
7/26/2012,07:00:00,167
7/26/2012,07:30:00,137
7/26/2012,08:00:00,169
7/26/2012,08:30:00,175
7/26/2012,09:00:00,168
7/26/2012,09:30:00,188
7/26/2012,10:00:00,137
7/26/2012,10:30:00,173
7/26/2012,11:00:00,164
7/26/2012,11:30:00,167
7/26/2012,12:00:00,115
7/26/2012,12:30:00,116
7/26/2012,13:00:00,118
7/26/2012,13:30:00,125
7/26/2012,14:00:00,104
```

Changes to original mbostock code: They mostly concentrate on y axis, while x xis remains same as original. Because the original mbostock code has numbers on y axis while I need 48 half hour interval buckets on y axis

I have added the following so that later on I can create a y axis of times:

```
var parseTimeBucket = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse,
    formatTimeBucket =d3.time.format("%H:%M");
```

Then changed domain this way:

```
var StartTime = parseTimeBucket("00:00:00");
var EndTime = parseTimeBucket("23:59:59");   
y.domain([StartTime, EndTime]);
```

Also added `ystep` in addition to `xstep`. `ystep` corresponds to 30 minute intervals

```
var xStep = 864e5,
    yStep = 18e5;
```

And then finally to build the axis I changed the third line (.call...)

```
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
       .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(d3.time.minutes, 30).tickFormat(formatTimeBucket).orient("left"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .text("Value");
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain what you've modified in the example you've started from? It would help us to pin down the problem much quicker.

Comment: i have added the changes as edit.

Comment: You can't use `ystep` like this. It's a time scale and you're passing it a number.

Comment: Can you please give more insight into this. xStep seems to have no issues as x axis scale is fine and heat map itself is fine. its only the y axis. considering xStep is working fine with a date scale (plain addiiton), what changes are required for yStep.

Comment: Ok, disregard that last comment. You're using your scale for `y` like a time scale (by using `d3.time.minutes` to compute the ticks), but it actually isn't. So to make the y ticks show you can either convert it to a time scale or use one of the conventional ways to specify the number of ticks.

Comment: Lars, I did not understand the explanation. Appreciate if you can exolain a little more.

Comment: Your y scale is a linear scale. You're using `.ticks(d3.time.minutes)` to set the ticks for the axis for that scale. You can only do this for time scales, not linear scales.

Comment: Lars, That was a silly thing to have been over looked on my part, but I can't thank you enough for pointing out this. Thanks a LOT. It works

Comment: You're welcome. I'll add it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

The scale for the y axis you're using is a linear scale. You're using `.ticks(d3.time.minutes)` to set the ticks for the axis for that scale. You can only do this for time scales, not linear scales. If you change either the way the ticks are computed or the type of scale it should work.